# How do I install Perl's Lingua::Lid?

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to install [Lingua::Lid](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-Lid) onto a unix system (ubuntu, latest version). Of course I am root. When I go into the package to install using `perl Makefile.PL` I get this dumb error:

```
[root@csisl27 Lingua-Lid-0.01]# perl Makefile.PL
/opt/ls//lib does not exist at Makefile.PL line 48.
```

I have tried playing with the path on line 48, nothing changes, here is what line 48-50 looks like:

```
Line 48: die "$BASE/lib does not exist"     unless -d "$BASE/lib";
Line 49: die "$BASE/include does not exist" unless -d "$BASE/include";
Line 50: die "lid.h is missing in $BASE/include" unless -e "$BASE/includ/lid.h";
```

The variable $BASE is declared as this:

```
$BASE = "/opt/ls/"         if ($^O eq "linux" or $^O eq "solaris");
$BASE = "/usr/local/"      if ($^O eq "freebsd");
$BASE = $ENV{LID_BASE_DIR} if (defined $ENV{LID_BASE_DIR});
```

Now the Perl program I am trying to write simply look like this (just my base):

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use Lingua::LinkParser;
 use strict;
 print "Hello world!\n";
```

When I run this trying to use Lingua, here is my error:

`[root@csisl27 assign4]# ./perl_parser_1.pl`

`Can't locate Lingua/LinkParser.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .) at ./perl_parser_1.pl line 3. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./perl_parser_1.pl line 3.`

I tried insalling this from cpan, still doesn't properly work.

Comment: When you try to install Lingua::LinkParser from The CPAN, what error do you get?

Answer (score 4):

Here is where the trouble begins when building [Lingua::LinkParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Lingua::LinkParser):

`LinkParser.xs:5:27: error: link-includes.h: No such file or directory`

I think you need to install [Link Grammar](http://abiword.com/projects/link-grammar/) first.

If you look at the [Makefile.PL](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DBRIAN/Lingua-LinkParser-1.14/Makefile.PL) that comes with the distribution, you can see the following comments:

```
# 'LIBS' => "-L/dbrian/link-grammar-4.4.3/link-grammar/.libs/ -llink-grammar", 
# 'INC' => "-I/dbrian/link-grammar-4.4.3/link-grammar/"
```

which means (very indirectly) that you either do not have [Link Grammar](http://abiword.com/projects/link-grammar/) installed on your system or it is installed in a non-standard location. If it is not installed, install it first. If it is installed, specify the correct location for `INC` and `LIBS`.

As the `README` states:

> Before you build this package, it is highly recommended that you install 
>      the link parser package with `make install`, which will put the libs, 
>      headers, and dictionary files in standard locations. This build no longer
>      prompts for package directories, so if you want to build with non-standard
>      locations, you'll need to edit Makefile.PL to make that happen. 
>      In particular,  pay attention to the `INCLUDE` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The Lid library is needed as prerequisite for `Lingua::Lid`. You did not install it. Buy it from its vendor: http://www.lingua-systems.com/request-quote/index.html?product=lid